# VB.net Problems with Openfiledialog

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm making this music player thing and I need help with some coding. I want my program to play a certain file when Checkbox1 is checked. I'm using OpenFileDialog but i'm not sure that's the right thing to do. I can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```
     If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
      ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop()
     End If
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *show* the dialog:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.Play()
    End If
Else
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.Stop()
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the dialog to display so the user can select a file, use ShowDialog() and check the return value to ensure a file was actually selected by the user:

```
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
        End If
    ElseIf CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop()
    End If
```